# Mouse cursor is unresponsive only on a certain user

Tags: windows, command-line, virus

Just today, while my dad was using his computer (ASUS Eee netbook) it looked like it froze up. But it only froze the cursor. The whole computer was still running and only the mouse cursor was unresponsive. The strange thing is that it only does that on his user. All the other users work just fine. So that means that the track pad is not broken. My best guess is that it's a virus.

Do you have any advice on what to do? I'm guessing that it might just be a background process that constantly disables the mouse's movement. But I don't know.

Comment: Have you restarted the computer?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows can/does store mouse settings on a per-user basis (at least there is a control panel/mouse registry key in HKCurrentUser). In addition, sometimes trackpads/mice have a taskbar tray icon with settings. These are usually vendor-written, launch at startup, and may include per-user settings.

Your father may have removed this software from his startup list.

(I am unsure if asus would somehow store the alt+fn key "trackpad off" setting per user, but I am skeptical)

Comment: It was a "trackpad off" setting. Fn+F3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could also be bad sectors on a hard drive. Try running `CHKDSK C: /f /r /b` from an elevated command prompt (Start->Type `cmd`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: While this isn't terrible advice, this does seem like awfully random behavior to be caused by this (and to have nothing else going wrong).  Have you seen a particular instance of something extremely similar?

Comment: @Shinrai Yup. Hard drive issues cause lots of fun problems. They're easy enough to check for, if you have patience. I have seen had hard drives affect only one user, although not the mouse issue, and I've seen hard drives get mirrored to new drives, then magically work again

Comment: I've certainly see myriad issues get fixed in that manner as well, but nothing quite so esoteric and (comparatively) minor as this, hence my curiosity.  Thanks for the input. :)